# How to read strings in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I have a question about `byteBufs` and the class `ByteBufUtil`.
Is it possible to read UTF8 after I wrote it?
I already searched on the internet but I haven't found an answer about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `byteBuf.readCharSequence(....)`. This allows you to read strings with different encodings / charsets.